# Joining a list of dicts

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, union

I have some list of dicts like this:

```
list1 = [
    dict(RL = 'rl1', 
        shaders = [dict(shader = "shader1", geom = ['a1','b1']),
        dict(shader = "shader2", geom = ['a2','b2'])]),
    dict(RL = 'rl3', 
        shaders = [dict(shader = "shader1", geom = ['c','d']),...])     
]
list2 = [
    dict(RL = 'rl1', 
        shaders = [dict(shader = "shader1", geom = ['p1','q1']),
        dict(shader = "shader3", geom = ['p3','q3'])]),
    dict(RL = 'rl2', 
        shaders = [dict(shader = "shader1", geom = ['c','d']),...])     
]
```

so it's a list of dicts where each dict has one of the values containing a list of dicts.
I'm aware it's not the best data structure ever but it would be quite time consuming to change that now. I would like to join all these lists by their RL value, and then if shader value is the same, join the geom lists together.
So for example for the lists above, assuming the only entries are the ones I written down, i would get my new list with same renderlayer rl1, same shader shader1, and the geom would be `['a','b','c','d']`
thanks for the help

Edit : Admitting I could change this bad data structure, what kind of structure should I use to make things easier for me? The only thing I want is to keep the hierarchy: one RL can contain many shaders which can contain many geoms, and I can have many entries like this.

Comment: The code pasted here is no Python. Correct your data structure

Comment: ok I was just too much in a rush to write it well... I use the equals when i use the dict() command. sorry about that i corrected it

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Yes, `dict` is the type, and any keyword arguments passed to it become key/value pairs. `dict(foo='bar')` is the same as `{'foo': 'bar'}`

Comment: @MartijnPieters actually he edited his previous `dict()` declaration which was incorrect.

Comment: ah, check. Still a syntax errors left there..

Comment: sorry no more syntax errors normally...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sticking with your data structure, I got this...

```
list1 = [dict(RL = 'rl1', shaders = [dict(shader = "shader1", geom = ['a','b']),
                                     dict(shader = "shader3", geom = ['q','p'])])]
list2 = [dict(RL = 'rl1', shaders = [dict(shader = "shader1", geom = ['c','d']),
                                     dict(shader = "shader3", geom = ['x','y'])])]
list3 = [dict(RL = 'rl1', shaders = [dict(shader = "shader2", geom = ['e','f'])])]
list4 = [dict(RL = 'rl2', shaders = [dict(shader = "shader2", geom = ['g','h'])])]
list5 = [dict(RL = 'rl2', shaders = [dict(shader = "shader2", geom = ['i','j'])]),
         dict(RL = 'rl3', shaders = [dict(shader = "shader4", geom = ['ab','cd'])])]

list_o_lists = [list1, list2, list3, list4, list5]

big_list_o_dicts = []
for x in list_o_lists:
    big_list_o_dicts.extend(x)

big_list_o_dicts.sort(key=lambda x: x['RL'])

new_list_o_lists = []

last_item = None
for item in big_list_o_dicts:
    if last_item and item['RL'] == last_item['RL']:
        for this_shader in item['shaders']:
            for last_shader in last_item['shaders']:
                if last_shader['shader'] == this_shader['shader']:
                    last_shader['geom'].extend(this_shader['geom'])
                    break
    else:
        last_item = item
        new_list_o_lists.append(last_item)
```

It looks crazy and there are definitely more efficient ways, but maybe it will help you out.

**EDIT:** In response to your edit, unless there is some reason to keep all these lists separate, your eventual desire to combine them all suggests that it would be easier to maintain the structure you want from the beginning.

Something like...

```
rl_shader_map = {
    'rl1': {
        'shader1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        'shader2': ['e', 'f'],
    },
    'rl2': {
        'shader2': ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
    }
}
```

makes checking for a shader in a render layer much easier (instead of iterating, it's a hashtable lookup).

Whenever you would have made a whole new list object, just append to or create the appropriate channel in the map above.

If you need to maintain more information than just `"geom"` for each shader, then I would move on to another dict like so...

```
rl_shader_map = {
    'rl1': {
        'shader1': {
            'geom': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        }
        'shader2': {
            'geom': ['e', 'f'],
        }
    },
    'rl2': {
        'shader2': {
            'geom': ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j'],
        }
    }
}
```

Also, just as a style point, using the kwarg dict creation is pretty unused AFAIK, so I would pass an iterable of key-value tuples like `dict([('RL', 'rl1'), ('shader', 'shader1')])` or use the `{}` syntax as I've done.

Whoa... holy crap... sorry for the rant.

Comment: @KevinEaverquepedo I thought the list of dicts was just the way you wrote the data structure.  My answer won't combine multiple shaders on the same RL.  I will edit it in a bit.

Comment: ok so even if it's a pain to change everything your solution makes sense.... What would be great would be to be able to keep my old data structure for all the code that uses it and translate it to the new data structure so I can do my new operations and code using this structure. I will look into that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @KevinEaverquepedo I think my last edit should allow you to do that pretty easily.

Comment: I thought it worked but it doesn't seem to... If instead of your 5 lists (which contain only one render layer per list, which is not the case for me), i take one list made from list1 and list2, but replacing rl1 by rl3 in list2, and then i take one made from list3 and list4, it outputs this:
[[{'RL': 'rl1', 'shaders': [{'geom': ['a', 'b'], 'shader': 'shader1'}, {'geom': ['q', 'p'], 'shader': 'shader3'}]}, {'RL': 'rl3', 'shaders': [{'geom': ['c', 'd'], 'shader': 'shader1'}, {'geom': ['x', 'y'], 'shader': 'shader3'}]}]]
Maybe my list was confusing cause i put only one per list, sorry...

Comment: What you're saying is that you don't think that my answer (which solved your original problem, second problem [via comments], *and* addressed your edit) was no longer deserving of an accept.  Are you kidding me?  Against my better judgment, I'm going to edit this, but jeez louise... what's a guy gotta do?

Comment: sorry i clicked on the thing by mistake your answer is really helping me. It's my first time posting something on starkOverflow so i'm kind of a noob.... sorry again...

Comment: I think my last edit accomplishes your goal, but again, just look at how much code it took to get the information you needed.  If you had used the `dict` hierarchy I suggested, this would have been handled by the python backend.

Comment: yes I see that, I'm probably going to rewrite the code at one point, but I needed and quick n' dirty solution... Thanks a lot again and sorry for all the trouble...

Comment: And just to make a point about my structure, i initially chose it so it would be really really easy to get values by key and for some stuff my structure really helps me... If I put as a key the name of the shaders, since they can differ in two entries, i can't do the same searches as easily...

Comment: Just one more time: thank you so much, I did not want to spend too much time resolving this and your solution works, so for the moment i can focus on more urgent issues... I really really appreciate it!

Comment: actually it didn't work for me. Works for the example above but when you start putting more shaders in each list it doesn't work. I wrote my own code and it works. But thanks for the advise about my data structures it will be very useful